# Understanding forest$xlevels in randomForest model

Tags: r, random-forest

Trying to build a randomForest model, where feature has both numeric and factor fields.

There's a field `model$forest$xlevels` which has levels of all the factor fields used, but also contains numeric fields with values of 0.

Why are numeric fields included in `xlevels` when 'levels' do not make sense for them.

Also, code from `predict.randomForest()`

```
 isFactor <- function(x) is.factor(x) & ! is.ordered(x)
 xfactor <- which(sapply(x, isFactor))
 if (length(xfactor) > 0 && "xlevels" %in% names(object$forest)) {
   for (i in xfactor) {
    if (any(! levels(y[[i]]) %in% models$rf$forest$xlevels[[i]]))
      stop("New factor levels not present in the training data")
  } 
}
```

In `predict.randomForest()`, there's code to check levels in model built (training data) and test data.

This code doesn't account for that fact there's numeric fields also present in `forest$xlevels` and hence fails cause it's doing index-by-index match.